Using EPSG 900913x2 gridset properly for high DPI display?
I have an OpenLayers map (version 9.1) that consumes GeoServer layers in EPSG:900913 projection (OpenLayers uses the compatible EPSG:3857 as it's default map projection).
There are two gridsets on GeoServer for 900913, there's EPSG 900913 and EPSG 900913x2. My understanding is that the regular 900913 gridset returns [256, 256] tile sizes, while 900913x2 returns [512, 512] tile sizes, making it more well suited for high resolution screens.
I saw this example on OpenLayers about how to setup your layers for high DPI screens and it manipulates the tilePixelRatio value of a WMTS source to serve 512x512 tiles on a 256x256 grid.
My thought is that when setting up a tile grid for a WMTS source, couldn't you just swap between the 900913 and 900913x2 gridsets depending on what the user's DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is? If it's 2+, you'd create the tile grid using 900913x2 and if it's 1 you'd create the tile grid with 900913, but I'm not sure I understand this correctly. This is my current code to create a WMTSTileGrid.
export const createTileGrid = (extent: Extent) => {
    //Setup basic layer parameters for web map tile services
    const projection = getProjection('EPSG:900913');
    const projectionExtent = projection?.getExtent();
    let tileSize: Array<number>;
    let size: number;
    let matrixSet: string;
    //Determine if using high resolution screen, then create tile grid
    if (DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO > 1) {
        matrixSet = 'EPSG:900913x2';
        size = getWidth(projectionExtent ? projectionExtent : []) / 512;
        tileSize = [512, 512];
    } else {
        matrixSet = 'EPSG:900913';
        size = getWidth(projectionExtent ? projectionExtent : []) / 256;
        tileSize = [256, 256];
    }
    let resolutions = new Array(31);
    let matrixIds = new Array(31);
    for (let z = 0; z < 31; ++z) {
        resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
        matrixIds[z] = `${matrixSet}:` + z;
    }
    const tile_grid = new WMTSTileGrid({
        origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent ? projectionExtent : []),
        extent: extent,
        tileSize: tileSize,
        resolutions: resolutions,
        matrixIds: matrixIds,
    });
    return tile_grid;
};

I'm not really seeing any problems display-wise with my code above, but I'm more interested to know that what I'm doing is actually valid for handling low and high DPI displays or if there is a better way to go about this.

Do not confuse 512 pixel tiles served to reduce the number of tiles loaded with hidpi tiles.
A tilegrid size of 512 is intended to reduce the number of network request to a quarter of that for tiles of size 256.
It is not the same as hidpi tiles which are served at twice the width and height specified in the tilegrid (512 or 1024 instead of 256 or 512) to produce clearer results.
Use a MapTiler key from https://cloud.maptiler.com/ and compare the difference.
One request to
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/2/2/1.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY

with a 512 tilegrid
produces the same result in a single request as 4 requests to
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/4/2.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/4/3.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/5/2.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/5/3.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY

with a 256 tilegrid.
Also with a 512 tilegrid a hidpi request
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/2/2/1@2x.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY

produces better quality output on a hidpi device (if tilePixelRatio: 2 is specified in the OpenLayers tile source options)
as does 4 requests to
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/4/2@2x.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/4/3@2x.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/5/2@2x.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/3/5/3@2x.jpg?key=YOUR_KEY

with a 256 tilegrid on a hidpi device.
